# Replace string from a huge python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
id_dict = {'C1001': 'John','D205': 'Ben','501': 'Rose'}
```

This dictionary has more than 10000 keys and values. I have to search for the key from a report which has nearly 500 words and replace with values.
I have to process thousands of reports within a few minutes, so speed and memory are really important for me.

This is the code I am using now:

```
str = "strings in the reports"
for key, value in id_dict.iteritems():
    str = str.replace(key, value)
```

Is there any better solution than this?

Comment: How much time & memory is your current code using?

Comment: Seems like you could get some speed by having several reports in the loop.

Comment: And your current code is correct? If I for example set `str` to `"I have 35014 goats."`, then you change that to `"I have 3Rose4 goats."`...

Comment: aside: _don't use_ `str` as a variable name as it is the python string class.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.replace` in a loop is very inefficient. A few arguments:

- when the word is replaced, a new string is allocated and the old one is discarded. If you have a lot of words, it can take ages
- `str.replace` would replace inside of words, probably not what you want: ex: replace "nut" by "eel" changes "donut" to "doeel".
- if there are a lot of words in your replacement dictionary, you loop through all of them (using a python loop, rather slow), even if the text doesn't contain any one of them.

I would use `re.sub` with a replacement function (as a `lambda`), matching a word-boundary alphanumeric string (letters or digits).

The lambda would lookup in the dictionary and return the word if found, else return the original word, replacing nothing, but since everything is done in the `re` module, it executes way faster.

```
import re

id_dict = {'C1001': 'John','D205': 'Ben','501': 'Rose'}

s = "Hello C1001, My name is D205, not X501"

result = re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b",lambda m : id_dict.get(m.group(1),m.group(1)),s)

print(result)
```

prints:

```
Hello John, My name is Ben, not X501
```

(note that the last word was left unreplaced because it's only a partial match)